# how to reset the following array in c?

Tags: c, arrays

I have a question regarding to reset array in c,
I define a array like this:

```
static int hello[5][6] = {{1,2,3,4,5,6},1,2,3,4,5,6},1,2,3,4,5,6},1,2,3,4,5,6},1,2,3,4,5,6}};
```

then how to reset all the element on each row and line as 0?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
memset (hello, 0, sizeof(hello));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try so: bzero(hello, sizeof(hello));

Comment: What is bzero? I've never heard of it, it is not part of the C standard.

Comment: `bzero(hello,size(hello));` is used inside calloc implementation and its an alias for
`memset (hello, 0, sizeof(hello));`